# Directory not available after git push

Tags: github, repository

I have uploaded some files in my private git repository but the "src" is not available. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not available"?

Comment: I click in the folder and nothing happens, I can't open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The src folder was in another repository, therefore it was not possible to open it in the browser.